# How can I upload an excel file with Spring Boot and Postman to a MySQL Database? - Status: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman

I'm working on a RESTful FAQ Webservice. So I decided to implement a import/download feature for excel files. Currently I'm focussing more on the upload feature. So to implement this feature I followed a Tutorial (https://bezkoder.com/spring-boot-upload-excel-file-database/) because I'm a newbie in Spring Boot or in programming in general.

So now if I want to upload my example Excel File there is actually no respond from Postman. You can see it in the picture below. Aswell Postman says Status: 401 Unauthorized. What does this mean and how can I fix that?

[image: Postman 401 Unauthorized]

ExcelController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/excel")
public class ExcelController {

  @Autowired
  ExcelService fileService;

  @PostMapping("/upload")
  public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    String message = "";

    if (ExcelHelper.hasExcelFormat(file)) {
      try {
        fileService.save(file);

        message = "Uploaded the file successfully: " + file.getOriginalFilename();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        message = "Could not upload the file: " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
      }
    }

    message = "Please upload an excel file!";
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
  }

  @GetMapping("/tutorials")
  public ResponseEntity<List<Tutorial>> getAllTutorials() {
    try {
      List<Tutorial> tutorials = fileService.getAllTutorials();

      if (tutorials.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
      }

      return new ResponseEntity<>(tutorials, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
  }

  @GetMapping("/download")
  public ResponseEntity<Resource> getFile() {
    String filename = "tutorials.xlsx";
    InputStreamResource file = new InputStreamResource(fileService.load());

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + filename)
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"))
        .body(file);
  }

}
```

Aswell I use Spring Security so the user needs to be logedin to see the website.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

//    @Override
//    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//        http.authorizeRequests()
//                .anyRequest().authenticated()
//                .and()
//                .formLogin().permitAll()
//                .and()
//                .logout().permitAll();
//    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/v1/signup");
    }
}
```

```
//    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//        http.authorizeRequests()
//                .anyRequest().authenticated()
//                .and()
//                .formLogin().permitAll()
//                .and()
//                .logout().permitAll();
//    }
```

I commented that out so I do not get always the Login page in Postman and get the actual page.

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_faq4?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=5MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
spring.mvc.dispatch-options-request=true
```

So if you need more Information say what you need. You can find the whole source code on github aswell. (https://github.com/bezkoder/spring-boot-upload-excel-files)

As I said I'm a beginner in programming. So feel free to say where my problems are and how can I improve them and myself and how can I get better in asking questions on stackoverflow so its easier for you to understand my problem.

Comment: 401 Unauthorized is the HTTP Status that tells you that a login is required to talk to your backend. This happens because you added Spring Security which comes with some defaults when nothing is configured (the defaults should be active since you commented the configuration). See: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-security-autoconfiguration#default-setup

Comment: Adding to above comment, if you are new and do not want to play with security, add this method to you security config and 401 error will be solved. @Override
     public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
   web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");  
     }. This method is to bypass spring security for any URL

Comment: Now i'm getting an other error. Status: 403 Forbidden and "Invalid CORS request". :/

Answer (score 1):

In your header try to pass the security token or the credentials like below:

headers.setBasicAuth("admin", "admin");

Give it a try with both one by one. Should work.